# Division of integers shows error as division by zero

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm using the regula falsi method to determine a function's roots but i'm getting a ZeroDivisionError when I try to use the formula.

Here's my code (jupyter notebook python)

```
def regulafalsi(f, itv0, its=20):

    a = itv0[0]
    b = itv0[1]
    
    for i in range(its):
        
        x = f(b)*a-f(a)*b
        y  = f(b)-f(a)
        
        c    = x/y
        
        if f(c)*f(a) > 0:
            a = c
        if f(c)*f(b) > 0:
            b = c
    return c
```

And I tried it using the function x^2+2x+3 with the interval (-2,3) so a=-2 and b=3.
The first c value should be -3 but that's where it returns the ZeroDivisionError.
Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: You should try using a debugger to find out where your implementation differs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `try` and `except` block where there is a possibility of DividebyZero error:

```
def regulafalsi(f, itv0, its=20):

    a = itv0[0]
    b = itv0[1]
    
    for i in range(its):
        
        x = f(b)*a-f(a)*b
        y  = f(b)-f(a)

        try:
            c = x/y
        except ZeroDivisionError as ze:
            pass
        
        if f(c)*f(a) > 0:
            a = c
        if f(c)*f(b) > 0:
            b = c
    return c
```

Comment: Thank you, that should do it. I also just realized that the function I'm trying to use can't be used for the regula falsi method.